# killBackgroundProcesses not working (for other app)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have my app turn off a music player using the code below:

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)      
context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String music = "com.sec.android.app.music";
    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(music);
  }

}
```

But it's only turning down the volume, not killing the application. I have added the appropriate permissions to the manifest and I'm targeting higher than API 8 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot kill other processes. Only system can do that. And volume goes down because its settings is not per app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hario.timer.sleep.music&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmhhcmlvLnRpbWVyLnNsZWVwLm11c2ljIl0. do it then?

Comment: By sending music player an intent it can understand and turn on/off itself